# Django 1.8 and Python 2.7 using PostgreSQL DB help in fetching

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-1.8

I'm making an application that will fetch data from a/n (external) postgreSQL database with multiple tables.

Any idea how I can use inspectdb only on a SINGLE table? (I only need that table)

Also, the data in the database would by changing continuously. How do I manage that? Do I have to continuously run inspectdb? But what will happen to junk values then?

Comment: Surely the structure of the database isn't changing continually. That's all inspectdb cares about.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, so you mean to say I should periodically call inspectdb so that my model is updated? or is it done automatically or something?

Comment: No, I don't understand what you mean. Inspectdb deals with the *structure* of the table, it has nothing to do with the data. The structure tends not to change.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, so when i refer to something from the model, from where is the data populated? is it fetched from the postgresql db in realtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what inspectdb does. It creates a model for an existing database table. It doesn't copy or replicate that table; it simply allows Django to talk to that table, exactly as it talks to any other table. There's no copying or auto-fetching of data; the data stays where it is, and Django reads it as normal.

Comment: Roserman, thanks for clearing it out to me. 
Can you please explain what does managed=False (or True) means?

Comment: It means that Django won't try to manage the structure of that table, eg by creating migrations.

Comment: Roserman, can you please elaborate a bit more, probably with an example? What exactly are migrations?

Comment: Not in a comment, no. You should read the documentation, especially the tutorial, where all this is fully explained.